# Namecheap domain cannot access website without www on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, namecheap

I am trying to link my namecheap domain to AWS EC2 instance.
For this purpose i followed this tutorial https://mkyong.com/server/namecheap-domain-name-and-amazon-ec2
Everything is setup perfectly but i can only access to with wwww.example.com, but not with example.com .

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Did you create the **two** `A-Record` entries in Amazon Route 53? Can you provide a screenshot? What happens when you try to resolve the domain name without `www` (eg use `nslookup example.com` or even just `ping example.com`) -- does it resolve to your IP address? Also, when you say "cannot access website", what happens?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein
Yes created the needed entries, posting a link with screenshots.
The error is - This site can’t be reached example.com took to long to respond. ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
https://postimg.cc/gallery/34dyf0P

Comment: What happens when you try to resolve the domain name without `www` (eg use `nslookup example.com` or even just `ping example.com`) -- does it resolve to your IP address?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein https://postimg.cc/gallery/b1kPvj5

Comment: Unfortunately you have hidden a lot of information in the screenshot. Do the results differ if you lookup/ping the `www.` version of the domain vs the non-www version? If the results are the same, then the DNS is configured correctly and the problem lies with your web server.

Comment: The results from lookup/ping with or without www are the same. The www version also timeouts when when trying to ping. The configuration on the web server seems correct.

Comment: The actual ping connection is not important (and won't actually succeed due to Security Groups blocking it) -- the question is whether `example.com` resolves to an IP address when trying to ping it or when using nslookup? If it _does_ resolve to the same IP address as www.example.com, then the problem is with your web server configuration.

Comment: Yes they resolve to the same IP

Comment: Since they both resolve to the same IP address, the DNS resolution is working correctly. Traffic will be sent to your web server. Therefore, the problem would be caused by the configuration of the web server.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.